# How can i hide API Key in an Electron JS Project?

Tags: node.js, api, security, electron

i'm working on an electron js app & i need to connect it to an API
knowing that the source code of an electron-js app is visible it's a huge security risk to leave the API key there !
how can i solve this problem ?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of having the electron app (whether from the page or from the main process) make a request to the API directly, you can have it make a request to your own server instead - then, your server can make the request to the API, so that the key is only visible to your server, and isn't exposed publicly anywhere.

This will also let you gate requests from clients - if, for example, the credentials a client sends don't match what you need, or if they make too many requests in too short a time, you can cut them off.

Answer (score 2):

You can't. If API key is shared, it's probably designed to be used in the backend.

The solution for that is to create a backend API for proxying API calls. Such proxying API should utilize authentication, so each user must send individual credentials.

Answer (score 0):

How about obfuscate it using a utility like js-beautify.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).